# How to get entire contents of binary tree in array form?

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-tree

I have a C structure that represents a binary tree:

```
struct btree {
    char *word; 
    int frequency; 
    struct btree *left; 
    struct btree *right; 
};
```

I want to create a function `btree_list(struct btree*)` that returns an array of all the `btree` objects in the binary tree passed to it. Order does not matter.

Here is an example of how this function would work:

```
struct btree *T = populate_with_random_values(); 
struct btree *entries = (struct btree*) malloc(sizeof(struct btree) * btree_size(T));

entries = btree_list(T);

while (*entries != NULL) {
    printf("There are %d occurences of the word %s", entries->frequency, entries->word); 
    entries++; 
}
```

Also for each element `E` in `entries`, `E->left` and `E->right` should be set to `NULL` since they aren't technically being used. How would I go about implementing this?

Comment: So you're aware, two lines malloc the `entries` array, and promptly leak all that memory with the very next line, which overwrites the address just-received by the return value of `btree_list`. So I hope it doesn't work *that* way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be the array:

```
typedef struct {
    struct btree **data;
    size_t count;
} t_tbl;

t_tbl *tbl_create(size_t count)
{
    t_tbl *new = NULL;

    if (count > 0) {
        new = malloc(sizeof(t_tbl));
        new->data = malloc(count * sizeof(struct btree *));
        new->count = 0;
    }
    return new;
}

void tbl_destroy(t_tbl *table)
{
    if (table) {
        free(table->data);
        free(table);
    }
}
```

And this could be the process:

```
void btree_populate_array(const t_node *root, t_tbl *table)
{
    if (root->left) btree_populate_array(root->left, table);
    table->data[table->count++] = root;
    if (root->right) btree_populate_array(root->right, table);
}

if (root) {
    t_tbl *table = tbl_create(btree_size);
    btree_populate_array(root, table);
    /* Do stuff with array */
    tbl_destroy(table);
}
```

You have to check `malloc`, if you don't know the size of btree:

```
void btree_count(const t_node *root, size_t *count)
{
    if (root->left) btree_count(root->left, count);
    (*count)++;
    if (root->right) btree_count(root->right, count);
}

size_t btree_size = 0;

if (root) {
    btree_count(root, &btree_size);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, do you want a preorder, inorder, or postorder traversal?

Here's a preorder example in pseudocode: (credit to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order))

```
iterativePreorder(node)
  parentStack = empty stack
  while not parentStack.isEmpty() or node ≠ null
    if node ≠ null then
      visit(node)
      if node.right ≠ null then
        parentStack.push(node.right)
      node = node.left
    else
      node = parentStack.pop()
```

You'll have to tweak this a bit in order to get it to return a list of the nodes, but the idea behind walking the tree is all there.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than returning the array just pass its base address to make your life easier and return the count of your array:

```
int TraverseTree(int arr[],btreenode *root, int depth)
{
    static int count = 0;
    if (root)
    {
        count++;
        TraverseTree(arr,root->right,depth+1);
        arr[depth]=root->data;
        TraverseTree(arr,root->left, depth+1);
    }
    return count;
}
```